# Winform on the mouse c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a loading screen, and I need the User mouse stay on behind the windows forms.
I searched the Internet and found nothing related to it. It is possible to create a form that is on top of the mouse pointer? (It seems a little crazy but that's it)

Sorry, my English is bad.

Comment: Does it need to actually be behind the form, or is it because you want to hide the cursor?

Comment: Is the purpose to stop the user clicking?

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I can think of is by hiding the mouse for the application.

```
Cursor.Hide();
```

Make sure you switch it back on when appropriate!

Note that users can get very confused when the mouse cursor disappears.

Comment: 'Apporiate' would be whenever the (invisible) mouse leaves the loading screen. - Even then it is a bad idea, imo!

Comment: @TaW - that depends on the actual requirements. Should it be hidden when over other forms of the same application? The question is not entirely clear on that.

Comment: Friend, the idea is I have the window so fixed on the screen and if the User wants, he may be using the mouse behind the form.

Comment: How would the user know what he is doing? Can you give an example of an existing application that does this so I will be able to understand better what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something similar with good code example.

// Set cursor as hourglass
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

// Execute your time-intensive hashing code here...

// Set cursor as default arrow
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

[How can I make the cursor turn to the wait cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568557/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-turn-to-the-wait-cursor)

Comment: How does this hide the cursor?

Comment: I copied the code example from the link i provided. However iam pretty sure that the information is enough to figgure out how to go from there. Especially considering that your answered the question as well.

Comment: I do not really need to change the cursor icon, I need the mouse pointer stay behind the form