# Showing Progress Bar until the data is received from the server C#

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a made a small tool which gets file size and name of the URL but it takes time (approx 4 seconds) when I run the code and enter a file URL it takes time for the user it will look like it is not working.

I want to show a progress bar until the data is received so that user may not think that the application is not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Multi_Tool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (textBox1.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have not typed the URL", "URL Error",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    string URL = textBox1.Text;
                    string filetype = URL.Substring(URL.LastIndexOf(".") + 1,
                            (URL.Length - URL.LastIndexOf(".") - 1));
                    FileType.Text = filetype.ToUpper();
                    string filename = URL.Substring(URL.LastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            (URL.Length - URL.LastIndexOf("/") - 1));
                    namelabel.Text = filename;
                    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);
                    req.Method = "HEAD";
                    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
                    long ContentLength = 0;
                    long result;
                    if (long.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out ContentLength))
                    {
                        string File_Size;

                        if (ContentLength >= 1073741824)
                        {
                            result = ContentLength / 1073741824;
                            kbmbgb.Text = "GB";
                        }
                        else if (ContentLength >= 1048576)
                        {
                            result = ContentLength / 1048576;
                            kbmbgb.Text = "MB";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = ContentLength / 1024;
                            kbmbgb.Text = "KB";
                        }
                        File_Size = result.ToString("0.00");
                        sizevaluelabel.Text = File_Size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear(); 
        }  
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If this would be my task, I would add a marqee progress bar to my usercontrol :)  - - - Really.. Where are you stuck?

Comment: If your tool is Web Application there are plenty of options to show progress bar & if it is Windows app use [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: to signal the user that he has to wait a while you could use the [hourglass cursos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568557/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-turn-to-the-wait-cursor) as generations of people watched this thingy turn and waited more or less calmly ;)

Comment: if i try like when the user click on get file size progress bar(marquee) will start in another thread until the label.text changed,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use a background worker to move your downloading to another thread and showing a progress bar until the data is received.

`ProgressForm` is a form which contains progress bar which you can show until data is downloaded

```
this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
// 
// progressBar1
// 
this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 30);
this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1;
this.progressBar1.Maximum = 2500;
this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(522, 23);
this.progressBar1.Style = System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 1;


//constructor
public frmProgress(string text)
{
   this.Text = text;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

> If you want to show value in your progress bar make sure to change the `properties` back to normal(which are set as `marquee` in answer as of now).But as you said it is going to take just 4 secs it would be good to use `marquee`

```
//Method to increment value of progress bar
public void PrgBarInc()
{
  if (this.IsHandleCreated)
  {
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
       this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(PrgBarInc));
    }
    else
    {
       prgBar.Increment("your val");
    }
}
```

==============================Main UI class==============================

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

//Add In your method which initiates download 
public void PerformDownload()
{
  ProgressForm = new frmProgress("your text");
  ProgressForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
  ProgressForm.ShowDialog();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //perform service request
   //if any of your task gets compeleted just call
   //ProgressForm.PrgBarInc()
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ProgressForm.Close();
    ProgressForm.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you update the progress bar like this:

```
progressBar1.Value = N;
```

Wrapping it within BeginInvoke() makes the UI responsive:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
               {
                   progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1;
                   //update in UI Thread
                   return null;
               }), null);
```