# Form not Responding when select database

Tags: c#

Every time when i open my program, it's say "Not Responding".
though on my form event load only retrieve data from database.

```
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //LoadDb_1()
 //LoadDb_2()
 //LoadDb_3()
}
```

i have tried to put the load database in the `form1_shown` event, but it's not working either.

how do i overcome this ?, i don't want to wait a several minutes to use the program.

PS: i have no idea how to use thread or async

**UPDATE**

example inside LoadDb_1()

```
   public void LoadDb_1()
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Datatable dt_main = new Datatable();
        try
        {
            dt_main.Clear();
            myConnection.Open();
            command.Connection = myConnection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "General.SP_Car";
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(dt_main);
            gridControl1.DataSource = dt_main;               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that the DB call is blocking the main thread. If you want it to be responsive, you're going to have to use async or run it on a separate thread.

Comment: @ZacFaragher could you give me an example how to use async and seperate thread ? some said to use background worker. but i don't quite understand it. some link would also a help

Comment: @chopperfield refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527050/showing-progress-bar-until-the-data-is-received-from-the-server-c-sharp/49527321#49527321) instead of server you use database

Comment: can you given an example of  whats in `LoadDb_1()`

Comment: @TheGeneral i have update it.

Comment: @Lucifer still can't figure it how. because what you are referring is progress bar ?

Comment: well I think you'll need some more of a basic answer , someone else will answer it

Comment: *" i don't want to wait a several minutes to use the program."* - the loading will take the same time whether on the UI thread (which leaves the app unresponsive) or on a background thread (which may require you to disable parts of the screen until the load has completed). You may need to consider whether you really need to load everything up front, or whether [lazy loading](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) would work.

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks. Once you've done that, you don't need to worry about `Close`ing the connection because the dispose will do it as you exit the block.

Comment: Please don't ever write `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a bad anti-pattern. You should always only catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully recover from.

Comment: @Richardissimo - Thank you.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your suggestion. but i think i still sticking using that

Answer (score 1):

You have blocking action, blocking the main thread, this is why your application in not responding, to fix this depends how you are connecting to the database, EF6 or EFCore, basic, dapper.... 
As you say, you don't know async programming or multithreading, one way to do it, connect to the database when you need, for example on some click, you then connect to the database, get the data and then shut the connection down, the application will not be responding for a few seconds, but that's one way... 
You have one big problem in your application as i say, not just not responding windows, you connection is always open, you shouldn't do that, you are making your app and your server vulnerable

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn  = new SqlConnection("your connection string....");
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand  myCommand = new SqlCommand("SQL query....", cnn);
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read()) 
            {
                 // Access the columns by reader["columnName"]
            }
            // Don't forget to close the connection
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }
```

Useful links:

1. Learn more about native c# to sql connection : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C
2. Use sqlconnection with winForms: http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sql-server-connection.htm
3. Connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/
4. Check on youtube for Tim Corey (https://www.youtube.com/user/IAmTimCorey) , he has great c# tutorials for Threading, async/await, dapper, ASP.NET and much more

Comment: i think the way i retrieve data is not wrong. between sqldataReader and sqldataAdapter, since i need to display it.

Comment: Try reading the links that i posted, you'll find some good stuff there, especially on tim corey channel, great guy, learned a lot from him

Comment: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable` so should be in using blocks. Once you've done that, you don't need to worry about `Close`ing the connection because the dispose will do it as you edit the block.