# Change cursor permanent to specific cursor on the whole screen

Tags: c#, forms, cursor

I have a easy winform with a button on it.

When I press the button, the cursor is like 1ms the cursor I want it to be, but than it instantly changes back to the default cursor.

How can i keep the cursor a cross? (Not only on the form, everywhere on the screen)

```
private void btn_takeScreenshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Cross;            
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the cursor turn to the wait cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568557/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-turn-to-the-wait-cursor)

Comment: @mirg thats the code I am using. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Look the second answer. The cursor change is temporary

Comment: @mirg okay i specified my question. Thank you.

Comment: I think the days of being able to globally change the cursor are long gone. I *believe* the common trick these days is to put up a form covering all screen(s) and make it fully-transparent, then change the cursor on the form.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good idea that should work. But I still have the problem, that the cursor doesn't stay "cross" and "Application" only stores a "Application.usewaitcursor" but I need the cross